# Actionbar using customview and menuitems

Tags: android

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.myLayout);

...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);

    menuBar = menu;

    return true;
}
```

myLayout.xml

```
< RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp" 
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/myImage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

myMenu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuItem1"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"
    android:title="@string/menu1">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuItem2"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu2">
</item>

</menu>
```

I have a custom view which I use to place an image in the center of the `ActionBar`. However, when I put the `MenuItem`s on the `ActionBar`, the image gets pushed to the left. I don't know how to center the image or fill the `RelativeLayout` to take the entire `ActionBar` width. I tried many different things but so far I had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your custom view to the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), you can set custom [ActionBar.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.LayoutParams.html) for your `View`.

To do what you're trying to do, you could change your code to something like:

mLayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp" 
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/myImage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Called somewhere in `onCreate(Bundle b)`:

```
public void setUpActionBar(){
     View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mLayout);

     ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

     final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
     bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
     bar.setCustomView(view, lp);

}
```

Comment: That works thanks. But I would run into a problem where if I have two images in my layout and I want to center one and left-align the other. How would I implement that? My initial guess would be to set the gravity layout to left inside the layout.xml file

Comment: Instead of using gravity in ActionBar.LayoutParams, set the layout_gravity attribute on each of your ImageViews in your XML (Note that if you do this, you'll have to change the width of your LinearLayout to MATCH_PARENT and not specify a gravity for the parent view).  An alternative to this, though, would be to add bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME); and set the home image as the image your want to left align.

Comment: The above didn't work for me. All the images were aligned to the left. I set the gravity to an image to center but it did not center.

Comment: Open a new question and provide a link to it under this comment.  This new issue you are trying to resolve differs from the original constraints of the question to much to try to explain in comments.